# Swagger 3 and SpringMVC how to describe POJO RequestParams

Tags: spring-mvc, swagger-ui, pojo, swagger-3.0, query-string

I have a simple SpringMVC controller

```
@RestController
@Validated
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UsersController {

  @GetMapping
  public String getAllUsers(@Valid Filter filter) throws MyCustomServiceException {
   [...]
  }
}
```

Since this endpoint has around 20 RequestParam instead of bloating the controller(s) with all the fields I have put them all nicely in a POJO (that actually can be reused in other controllers that needs similar query params filters)

```
public class UserFilter extends GenericRequestParams {
  [...] 
  private String email;
  [...] 
}
```

Now the problem is that Swagger doesn't consider that `UserFilter` and its fields to be query params but a simple Object so on the Swagger UI it become useless since it's hard to test that endpoint.

Is there a way to instruct swagger that `UserFilter` fields needs to be considered query params?

Comment: hi, do you have solved this problem

Comment: Yes use `@ParameterObject` in the controller before your object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magic annotation is `@ParameterObject`

```
@GetMapping
  public String getAllUsers(@Valid @ParameterObject Filter filter) throws MyCustomServiceException {
   [...]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@ApiParam` annotation in your model class annotated with `@ModelAttribute` so swagger generates this field into the UI.

```
public class UserFilter {
    @ApiParam(value = "the user email", required = true)
    private String email;
}
```

Comment: Swagger 3 doesn't have ApiParam (its equivalent is `@Parameter) but unfortunately I have tried using "@ModelAttribute" in the controller but Swagger still didn't consider these as query params